# What is significance of linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra

If there is vectors,  $ v_1,v_2,...$ .

They are linearly independent if $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+... = 0$ with $c_1=c_2=...=0$.

- if $v_1,v_2,...$ are linerly independent and so what?
- what will the linear independence of vectors lead to? Base?
- Do linear independence has any connection to dot product or orthogonality?
- what will happen if they are not linearly independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearly independence means $c_i=0$ is the *only* way to achieve $c_iv_i=0$. It follows you can't write any one vector as a linear combination of the others, so the space they span together can't be spanned by any proper subset of them. In an inner product space, you [can make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) an orthogonal basis from independent vectors, but they're not guaranteed to be one.

Answer (score 1):

Linear independence means that no vector in the set can be deduced from the others, so if you drop one, the *span* (i.e. the space that can be built on these vectors) reduces.

E.g. in 3 space, if three vectors are linearly dependent, they are coplanar. If you drop one, the span is still a plane.

Comment: Even in a linearly dependent set it may be possible to drop a vector and have the span be reduced. Although if this is true for every vector, then the set is linearly independent.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: you are right, but I didn't want to clutter my answer with details.